# How to show (1)$E|X_k|=\infty$ ; (2)$n P(|X_k|>k)\rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots $ be i.i.d with $P(X_k=(-1)^k k)=c/(k^2 log k)$ for $k\ge2$ where C is chosen to make the sum of the probabilities $=1$. Show that:

(1)$E|X_k|=\infty$ ;  (2)$n P(|X_k|>k)\rightarrow 0$.

(1) $P(X_k=x_k)=\sum_{k\ge2}c/(k^2 log k)=c\sum_{k\ge2}1/(k^2 log k)=1$.

Thus $c=1/\sum_{k\ge2}1/(k^2 log k)$.

Thus $E|X_i|=\sum_{k\ge2}kc/(k^2 log k)=\sum_{k\ge2}c/(k log k)=c\sum_{k\ge2}c/(k log k)=1/\sum_{k\ge2}1/(k^2 log k)\sum_{k\ge2}c/(k log k)$.

My question is how to show $E|X_i|=\infty$ as shown above.

(2) $n(P|X_i|>n)=n \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}c/(klogk) \leq n \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}c/(nlogk) \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}c/(klogk).$

My question is how to show $$n(P|X_i|>n)\rightarrow 0$ as shown above.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $k\mathbb P(|X_k|>k)\to 0$?

Comment: Wait, do you also mean to say that $\mathbb P(X_1 = (-1)^k) = c/(k^2\log k)$? As you've written it, it suggests that the distributions of the $X_k$ vary with $k$, which contradicts the assumption that the $X_k$ were i.i.d.

Answer (score 1):

> $(k \log(k))^{-1}$ diverges by integral test.

As for $c \sum_{k > n} \dfrac{n}{k^2 \log (k)} \leq \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k>n} \dfrac{1}{(\frac{k}{n})^2 \log(\frac{k}{n})} \sim \dfrac{1}{n} \int\limits_1^\infty dt\ \dfrac{1}{t^2 \log t}.$

Comment: My question is though $(klog(k))^{-1}$ diverges by integral test, how about C$\sum 1/(k^2 log(k))$, can we use $$

Comment: $c$ is a value that is constant, do not replace it anywhere with some series because it will lead you nowhere. Also, $c$ does not affect any limit!

Comment: My question is though $(klog(k))^{-1}$ diverges by integral test, how about $C\sum 1/(k^2 log(k))$, it seems that we can not get whether C is bounded directly.

$C=1/\sum_{k\ge2}1/(k^2 log k)\sim \int
_1^n 1/(x^2logx)dx$ to approximate it,   It seens that the question only mentioned that c is chosen to make the sum equal to 1.  It does not mentioned whether it is bouned.

Comment: $\log(k) > 1$ for $k \geq 3,$ so $(k^2 \log k)^{-1} \leq k^{-2},$ the later is known to converge.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! why(1) $c \sum_{k > n} \dfrac{n}{k^2 \log (k)} \leq \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k>n} \dfrac{1}{(\frac{k}{n})^2 \log(\frac{k}{n})}$ and $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k>n} \dfrac{1}{(\frac{k}{n})^2 \log(\frac{k}{n})} \sim \dfrac{1}{n} \int\limits_1^\infty dt\ \dfrac{1}{t^2 \log t}.$

Comment: The first one is algebra and the second one (the $\sim$) needs some justification, but I leave it to you.